# Moving log file kafka to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to move log file from kafka to hdfs file system. 
Which tools are used for this process ? I tried Confluent but i cant success this process with confluent. I try to found another tool.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at: https://nifi.apache.org/

Comment: Can i move log file with nifi ?

Comment: Do you mean, can you connect to kafka and consume messages? Yes, you can do this with NiFi.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to move log file from kafka to hdfs file system. Which tools are used for this process

The [HDFS connector for Kafka Connect](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html) works well, and is widely used with great success.

> i cant success this process with confluent

Probably best if you describe the actual issues that you're facing. If you're hitting problems with one proven technology, switching to another is not necessarily going to help you much.